# How to add space between checkbox and label value in p:selectmanymenu dropdown

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, selectmanymenu

I have a requirement to have a space between the checkbox and dropdown list items, where dropdown items are dynamically retrieved from BackingBean.

I tried

```
itemLabel="#{''.concat(' ').concat(bean.listValues)}"
```

I also tried taking an emptyString variable from backing bean and concatanating it.

```
itemLabel="#{bean.emptyString.concat(' ').concat(bean.listValues)}"
```

Comment: I tried. But its not working. would you mind sharing the syntax?

Comment: Show what you tried (css and client-side html) and we'll comment on it

Comment: div# div.ui-chkbox {
           margin-right: 6px !important;
        } i gave something like this with the div id in css and it worked

Comment: Can you please create this as an answer?